# Spring boot + spring-boot-starter-web + RestController + runBlocking

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm quite new to SB and I know there is WebFlux but what speaks against the combination WebMvc + Kotlin coroutines?

```kotlin
    @GetMapping("/wait")
    fun waitForSeconds(@RequestParam(value = "seconds", defaultValue = "1") seconds: Long): String = runBlocking {
        val now = DateTime.now()

        val first = async {
            waitAndGive(seconds, 1)
        }
        val second = async {
            waitAndGive(seconds, 2)
        }

        val result1 = first.await()
        val result2 = second.await()

        val then = DateTime.now()

        val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss")
        """
            Diff between: ${formatter.print(now)} and ${formatter.print(then)} is: 
            ${Seconds.secondsBetween(now, then).seconds}sec(s)<br>
            Result1: $result1 / Result2: $result2 
        """.trimIndent()
    }

suspend fun waitAndGive(wait: Long, giveMe: Int): Int {
    delay(wait * 1000)
    return giveMe
}
```

If I feed in 15secs it returns:

```
Diff between: 09:46:25 and 09:46:40 is: 15sec(s)
Result1: 1 / Result2: 2
```

So the two async-calls ran in parallel - good!

**This works just nice or are there any hidden problems I didn't realize?**

What I think how it works:

1. A request comes in
2. Tomcat picks a new/existing thread from it's thread-pool
3. Kotlin kicks in and runs the two coroutines in parallel (within this thread)
4. runBlocking "normalizes" everything for the RestController

Do you agree? Do I miss something?

Comment: WebMVC + co-routines is basically async servlet-api which is not comparable to Webflux which is fully non-blocking. They solve different issues.

Comment: I know and I am OK with the external blocking nature of WebMVC.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/live/szl3eWA0VRw?si=KouSZhIpxOKR90SC&t=3609
late to the party. but here you get a good example